# Unable to navigate to a specified page using iMacros

Tags: windows, imacros

Here is the iMacros code with which I'm trying to navigate to page 4:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frmThis ATTR=CLASS:ui-pg-input CONTENT=4.
```

[image: screenshot]

What happened is that when I played it, the document went to page 0, not page 4 (`CONTENT=4`).

Comment: Do you want to go to page 4, or do you want to go to page 0? Your question is unclear.

Comment: i want to go to page 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is the issue here?

Instead of

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frmThis ATTR=CLASS:ui-pg-input CONTENT=4
```

use

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frmThis ATTR=CLASS:ui-pg-input CONTENT=0


TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frmThis ATTR=CLASS:ui-pg-input&&TXT:0
```

Comment: i tried putting the content to 0, but yeah it turned to page 0. but obviously that's not i want to happen.

Comment: Try putting different number. If this is some kind of next page button then try using the last command in the post. I will edit it now.

Comment: Better way is to click Next button 4 times. Record that command and play it 4 times.

Comment: Thanks IceD. Really appreciate it.